# Pyserial issue: Not able to load

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have Python version 2.7 installed in my system, which is Windows OS 64 bit.

I installed pyserial, from the page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

Now, the issue is that I am getting an error:

C:\rk\Python27\pythonprograms>python

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (I
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more informati
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\rk\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line
e>
    from serial.serialwin32 import *
  File "C:\rk\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", li
dule>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\rk\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

When I import other packages, they are getting imported successfully:

```
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

Also, if I import pyserial in the directory `"C:\rk\Python27\python"`:

```
C:\rk\Python27>python
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import serial
>>>
```

What's the reason and how to fix this issue?

Kindly help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

I was opening Python exe as the 32 bit one, where as I had installed Python 2.7 for 64 bit with an amd extension.

I installed the python version recently, but, forgot to change the old compiler.